# viewDidLoad crashes when returning from background

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, autorelease, viewdidload

I recently enabled multitasking with an app (doesn't exit when backgrounded) and now have users getting crashes at unpredictable times. The crash logs show the crashes occur in viewDidLoad.

My viewDidLoad approach probably needs rethinking anyway. I have some of the view loaded from the xib, then I build the rest of the hierarchy programmatically (including some autoreleased UIButton's, which I think are the crashing culprit).  Any insight into what could be going on and how to approach this better?

Here's a typical crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x49ef527e
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32da1c9a objc_msgSend + 18
1   App                         0x0000a890 -[EntryViewController viewDidLoad] (EntryViewController.m:270)
2   UIKit                           0x3241ff08 -[UIViewController view] + 104
3   UIKit                           0x3242c1ce -[UIViewController viewControllerForRotation] + 34
4   UIKit                           0x3242ca40 -[UIViewController shouldWindowUseOnePartInterfaceRotationAnimation:] + 8
5   UIKit                           0x3242c9a8 -[UIWindow _clientsForRotation] + 236
6   UIKit                           0x32494fea -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 70
7   UIKit                           0x32493f9e -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 946
8   UIKit                           0x324bec50 -[UIViewController _dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:from:] + 1444
9   UIKit                           0x324be5e0 -[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:] + 596
10  UIKit                           0x324be366 -[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:] + 86
```

What would be most helpful is a quick rundown on best practices for managing the view hierarchy across the load/unload cycle.  I know IBOutlet's should be retained properties that get set to nil in viewDidUnload.

But what about programmatically created UIView's and UIControl's?  Ok to create a local object in viewDidLoad, add it to the view, and release it, never worrying about it again? Ok to use alloc-init'ed views in ivars that I don't release till dealloc? Ok to use autoreleased views that I never release?

Here's some of my viewDidLoad:

```
imagebg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imagebg];
[self positionBackgroundAt:0];

UIButton *flickbtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[flickbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(flick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:flickbtn];
[flickbtn release];

// SET UP UPPER LEFT BUTTONS
upperLeftButton0 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[upperLeftButton0 setFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:upperLeftButton0];
upperLeftButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[upperLeftButton1 setFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:upperLeftButton1];

// SET UP DISPLAY
displayimg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newdisplay.png"]];
[displayimg setCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame),CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame) - 57)];
[self.view addSubview:displayimg];
[displayimg release];
```

...

My viewDidUnload just sets all IBOutlets to nil.

Thanks.

Comment: You should post some code and the error stack that you're getting.

Comment: As j0k said, you need to show us some code to narrow down what is the problem

Comment: I suppose you access object released in `viewDidUnload`, which wasn't set to `nil` after release.

Comment: How about showing your `viewDidUnload` and `veiwDidLoad` definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Without your code and resulting error, here is my best suggestion for probable memory issues: First, use the "Analyze" function from the "Product" menu, and resolve all warnings raised.  If you still have the issue, profile it and use the allocation or leak profiler to track your memory.  Finally, debug sections that are having issues and view the memory stack to see what is actually there in viewDidLoad as compared to when the application crashes.  Recently I accidentally used assign instead of retain in one of my properties and ended up with a similar issue.  As stated above, make sure to set nil your released objects.  The quickest way to release and nillify retained properties is:

```
self.myProperty = nil;
```